# open google doc by id

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

What I am trying to do is make a copy of a template doc, the append sheet data to the new file.
I am using the doc URL as the id. However, when I try to access the file I am getting this error
"Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted?) (line 21)"
Line 21 is

```
    var templateid = "URL";
    var file = DocumentApp.openById(templateid);
```

Can anyone advise on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 18):

The document id is not the URL of the document, but it is a UID generated when the document is created, e.g., it is the value of id after `var id = createDocWithTable("doc with table")`.

You need to keep track of this id separately.  If you have the document object, you can retrieve it with its `getId()` method.  The ID is also encoded into the URL, so `https://docs.google.com/document/d/3ckYOu8kuIfBzbu-Dtu9XwGHUnUJG32PK7wHe5xMv3VG/` has document id `3ckYOu8kuIfBzbu-Dtu9XwGHUnUJG32PK7wHe5xMv3VG`